# Material table with sticky header and sticky columns with action item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**code which i have tried for sticky header and sticky column , issue is that both are not working together tried so many option but some time sticky header is not working with horizontal scroll and some last column action item is not visible if define right side sticky column**

```
<MaterialTable
   columns={columns
            .filter(l => selectedColumns.includes(l.field as keyof T))
            .map(val => ({
              ...val,
              headerStyle: {
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                // minWidth: '400px',
              },
              cellStyle: {
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                // minWidth: '400px',
              },
            }))}
          localization={localization}
          icons={icons}
          options={{
            ...options,
               // paging: false,
                maxBodyHeight: '550px',
              headerStyle: { position: 'sticky',top: 0},
              overflowY?: "scroll",
            //  actionsCellStyle?: { paddingRight: '23px'},
            selection: showMultiSelector,
            //actionsColumnIndex: 0,
            fixedColumns: fixLeftMostColumn
              ? {
                  right: -1,
                }
              : {},
          }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

found some solution but looking same above example with material ui and react.
https://codesandbox.io/s/bn7c7?file=/demo.js
Material table with sticky header and sticky columns with action item